# Modify data during Serialization - C# - Json.Net

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

I have one seializable class in C# as below

```
   namespace DataRequest
  {
   [Serializable]
  public class BaseData
    { 
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "u_additional_info")]
    public string DeskNumber { get; set; }
   }
  }
```

I am fetching data from Database and mapping to this class.I have requirement

1. DeskNumber will contain data in following format

   Format1.

   ```
     <AdditionalInfo><Number>164</Number></AdditionalInfo>
   ```

   Format2

   ```
    AdditionalInfo><Code>GLW51</Code><Lang>GLW51</LangCode><TzCode>GLW51</TzCode></AdditionalInfo>
   ```

   During serialization if data is 1st fromat  i need to return value under  tag (ie .164).Value under Number tag will be different at different time.So need a logic find value under Number tag .If data  is in any other format other than "Format1" then return it as blank .

   Or

**I am okay on applying ths logic even if its during setting value rather than during serialisation**

Can anyone help on this

Comment: You would typically do this by implementing custom Json serialization. e.g. in conjunction with the JsonConverter attribute Google for "Json.Net custom serialization"

Comment: Format1 and Format2 are file contents coming in at different times?

Comment: Format1 and Format2 are simple string format that i fetching it from database.So rather than complicating serializer logic,is it possible to apply this logic in set method of DeskNumber property.Fetching from db itself i can modify the data

Answer (score 0):

Use the Following code, You will get Value under the Number Tag. resultingMessage.Number contains the required result

```
string name = YourXmlNodes;

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AdditionalInfo));
MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(name));
AdditionalInfo resultingMessage= (AdditionalInfo)serializer.Deserialize(memStream);


namespace ConsoleApplication1
    {
        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "AdditionalInfo")]
        public class AdditionalInfo
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "Number")]
            public string Number { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> if **Format1** and **Format2** are same file contents coming in at different
>   times you can be spesitifcly serialized XmlContent this code

**Try this**

```
        // Generic DeSerialization metod.
        public T DeSerialization<T>(string xmlStrig)  where T : class
        {
            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            using (StringReader sReader = new StringReader(xmlStrig))
            {
                return (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(sReader);
            }
        }

        // Accepted class
        [Serializable]    
        public class AdditionalInfo
        {
            [XmlElement]
            public string Number { get; set; }
        }

        // DeSerialize to Object code
        // if you have Xml-string you can send parameter XmlString directly
        // string xmlString = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"..\\XMLFile1.xml");
        AdditionalInfo ast = DeSerialization<AdditionalInfo>(yourXmlString);
```

You can check [www.bilisim.io](http://bilisim.io/2017/02/11/net-serialization-deserialization/) for detailed information

Comment: Can u Pls look on the comment that i added below question

Comment: Format1 and Format2 are simple string format that i fetching it from database.So rather than complicating serializer logic,is it possible to apply this logic in set method of DeskNumber property.Fetching from db itself i can modify the data